# Java Logging Across Multiple Environments

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Our team is trying to get to a Single Build state; the build that's sent to Test is the same build that gets promoted to Staging->etc->Production. Right now setting up logging for different environments is a bit of a sticking point (currently we use Maven Profiles and filter the logger config at build time).

**We have many web applications and I'd like the logging to be defined by the app and configurable by the environment it's deployed to.**

We use Log4j though we're open to different implementations that could make this work. We'd like the app to be able to define the loggers as some apps may want specific logging on certain packages but, ultimately, I want the environment to be able to configure logging paths and levels. For example, the QA environment may typically have `INFO` level logging on the `com.foo.bar` package but, if they run into a sticky issue, they may wish to bump that up to `DEBUG`. I don't want to have the app redeployed since that technically changes the build.

With minimal poking around I found that log4j can directly use system properties, so a setup like this would be possible:

```
<appender name="someAppender" class="com.whatevs.SomeAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${logger.path}/some_app.log"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</appender>
<logger name="com.foo.bar">
    <level value="${logger.level.com.foo.bar}"></level>
</logger>
<root>
    <priority value="${logger.priority}"/>
    <appender-ref ref="someAppender"/>
</root>
```

My concern is that as the number of apps deployed and number of loggers defined increases, the overhead of maintaining the system properties could become cumbersome:

```
-Dlogger.path=/var/log -Dlogger.priority=INFO -Dlogger.level.com.foo.bar=WARN ...
```

I'm sure this issue has been tackled before. What's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been several attempts to make this better but no one has come up with a "standard" solution so far:

- You can configure the logging with an [MBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/index.html).

  Pro: You can easily change the config remotely at runtime
  Con: You can't save/collect a config "profile" (i.e. a useful set of configs) this way.
- You can make your logging framework to load the config from outside the web app.

  Pro: Config can easily be collected in a file.
     You can use build time scripts to generate them from templates, etc.

  Con: You need to keep these files somewhere, backup/install them, etc.
  You better figure out a way to load a default config when none can be found
- You can allow the application to switch configs at runtime. Just make sure that the initial config is useful to debug startup problems
- Some logging frameworks like logback allow to include config files. That makes it easy to load a shared config and then use a single system property to specify which include file to load with overrides.

At the moment, I prefer the last approach because it allows any number of special configs. The testing team can have their own, manager it themselves, put it wherever they like, update it at their leisure.

Note that replacing log4j with slf4j/logback means just replacing a couple of JAR files. If you use Maven, it takes 2 Minutes (just add `logback-classic` and `log4j-over-slf4j` as dependencies and remove `log4j`)

Comment: Follow up: We decided to go with Logback as it was more configurable than log4j. We set it up to read props from a file (`<property file="${config.location}/logger.properties"/>`) with `-Dconfig.location=/path/to/config` passed to the VM. We haven't finalized on how to manage those files yet but probably through Puppet or some other configuration management tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use Log4j api to set up log levels through the code. So depending on the environment, on app startup, you can set up the log configuration. You can even make it configurable at runtime by providing appropriate UI to define the log levels for different packages, of course, if required.